# How to add PowerBI Sample Dashboard to static website

Tags: javascript, html, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to add a sample PowerBi dashboard to a static website... the purpose is simply a design idea I want to present. 
I have attempted to embed the sample dashboard from "https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/v2-demo/index.html# " I have used this in my html

```html
<iframe width="800" height="600" src="https://app.powerbi.com/dashboardEmbed?dashboardId=b5f50796-6e97-4dc5-a755-00cf4405e029&groupId=be8908da-da25-452e-b220-163f52476cdd&config=eyJjbHVzdGVyVXJsIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9XQUJJLVVTLU5PUlRILUNFTlRSQUwtcmVkaXJlY3QuYW5hbHlzaXMud2luZG93cy5uZXQifQ%3d%3d?rs:Embed=true" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
```

[I am getting this error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKmKd.png)

Is it possible to have a sample dashboard or is my idea simply not possible without other requirements being fullfilled?

Comment: Probably your `dashboardId=` or `config=` parameters are invalid.

Comment: @Joey please accept the answer if your question sorted because system still identify your question is not sorted yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The new Embed option is available on the File menu for reports in the Power BI service.**

[image]

Select the Embed option to open a dialog that provides a link and an HTML snippet that can be used to embed the report securely. You’ll need to use use your portal’s embed feature or edit the web page’s HTML to add the report.

[image]

**Notes**
If you are using power bi desktop you need to publish report to power bi service.

**Sample code for test!**

```
<iframe width="800" height="600" src="https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiZjY3MmUwMDctYzQ2Yi00MjM2LTgxYzgtNThmODI2ZjE0ZmZjIiwidCI6ImRjZTZkMWZjLTc1NjctNDFjMy05OWZlLWRkNDhjNDgwYzAwMyIsImMiOjEwfQ%3D%3D" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: I am not using the PowerBI service at the moment, I am starting to think that may be my issue. I am simply trying to add that sample code to my HTML but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I have copy/pasted from the sample code into my HTML but I am not sure if that possible without using the service fully

Comment: @Joey you can used someones embed code in your html if no auth required! You can used power bi service for 3 months for free for testing.